# Determining the invariant factors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to find the invariant factors of the following matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $(x-2)^4$ and minimal polynomial is $(x-2)^2$. So there are two possibilites for what the matrix's invariant factors are: $\lbrace (x-2)^2, (x-2)^2 \rbrace$ and $\lbrace (x-2)^2, (x-2), (x-2) \rbrace$. From here, how do I determine which is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

After some minutes of pondering, I found the answer myself. Let $T$ be the matrix denoted by the matrix. Note that for $v_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0)$, $Tv_1 = (2, 1, 0, 0)$ is not a multiple of $v_1$. Now note that for $v_2 = (0, 0, 1, 0)$, $Tv_2 = (0, 0, 2, 0)$ is a multiple of $v_2$. Finally, for $v_3 = (0, 0, 0, 1)$, $Tv_3 = (0, 0, 0, 2)$ is a multiple of $v_3$. As $v_1$ spans $T$-cyclic subspace of dimension 2, $v_2$ of dimension 1 and $v_3$ of dimension 1, the invariant factors of the matrix are $\lbrace (x-2)^2, (x-2), (x-2) \rbrace$.